# Display database value on label in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I'm trying to use datareader to display out specific value from specific table in the database. As you can see from my sql query, i uses datas from 3 separate tables and memberreportid and username has a PK and FK r/s.
Unfortunately, i wasn't able to display out the value i wanted as stated below.

This is the error i recevied

**IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled by user code**

I comment the display out value codes line by line and indeed all of received the above error

Here are my codes.

```
protected void DDLCase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = project; Integrated Security = SSPI");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select * from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and caseprogress='settled'", con);
        SqlDataReader dr;
        dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            lblFullName.Text = dr["lro.fullname"].ToString();
            lblContact.Text = dr["lro.contact"].ToString();
            lblTOC.Text = dr["mr.typeofcrime"].ToString();
            lblLocation.Text = dr["mr.location"].ToString();
            lblCRDT.Text = dr["mr.CRdatetime"].ToString();
            lblPicture.Text = dr["picture"].ToString();
            lblAssign.Text = dr["pr.policeid"].ToString();
            lblPRDT.Text = dr["pr.PRdatetime"].ToString();
            lblCR.Text = dr["mr.citizenreport"].ToString();
            lblPR.Text = dr["pr.policereport"].ToString();
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are selecting all rows using "*" but then you are trying to access them with table aliases. Either way change your query:

```
Select mr.location, mr.typeofcrime ... etc from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.memberreportid =
```

or access them in `datareader` without aliases:

```
lblFullName.Text = dr["fullname"].ToString();
```

also I strongly advise to use parameters!

```
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("Select mr.location, mr.typeofcrime ... etc from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.memberreportid = @id and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and caseprogress='settled'");
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from MemberReport mr, PoliceReport pr, LoginRegisterOthers lro where pr.memberreportid = '" + DDLCase.SelectedItem.Text + "' and mr.memberreportid=pr.memberreportid and lro.username=mr.username and caseprogress='settled'", con);

    DataTable tbl = new DataTable();

adapter.Fill(tbl);

foreach(DataRow row in tbl.Rows)
{
 //use row data here as row["column_name"].ToString()
}
```

---

[SqlDataAdapter](http://www.dotnetperls.com/sqldataadapter) example